# In android, the host PC can accessed on the ip 10.0.2.2. Is there a way devices plugged in via USB to access the host?

Tags: android

In android, the host PC can accessed on the ip 10.0.2.2 ([according to this doc](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html)). Is there a way devices plugged in via USB to access the host?

The context is I'm hopping to run a wiremock server as part of the gradle build process to aid testing. [Wiremock doesn't run in android](https://github.com/tomakehurst/wiremock/issues/53) without significant work so running it on the host PC seems like the much simpler option.

Comment: This has been covered here before.  Basically your options are an ingoing ADB port forward from which you then setup an ssh tunnel so things on the phone can reach back out to the PC, or to take advantage of most USB tethering configurations creating an ordinary bidirectional network between the device and PC, which you can use for local traffic (but be careful if the device has a data plan not to accidentally route external traffic through it).

Comment: Hmm - Now I want too know what and ADP Port forward is ( ssh run on the PC to the device, or ssh run on the devide to the pc?)  I have the same issue I am testing the device client with a server and have no wifi in some places.

Answer (score 0):

**WireMock now works in an Android app as of January 2016 without having to do anything special.**  This issue fixed as of a couple of weeks ago with WireMock 2.0.8-beta from the [2.0-beta branch](https://github.com/tomakehurst/wiremock/tree/2.0-beta).  I've updated that [WireMock GitHub issue](https://github.com/tomakehurst/wiremock/issues/53) and have created a [sample project showing it working](https://github.com/handstandsam/AndroidHttpMockingExamples).

This allows you to not have to worry about connecting to the host over USB.  You can run the WireMock server ON the Android device and connect to localhost.

Here are the build.gradle dependencies you'll need to use it:

```
androidTestCompile("com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock:2.0.8-beta") {
    //Allows us to use the Android version of Apache httpclient
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'

    //Resolves the Duplicate Class Exception
    //Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebugAndroidTest'.
    //       > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/objectweb/asm/AnnotationVisitor.class
    exclude group: 'asm', module: 'asm'

    //Fixes conflict with Android's version
    //Warning:Dependency org.json:json:20090211 is ignored for debugAndroidTest as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
    //In case of problem, please repackage with jarjar to change the class packages
    exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
}
androidTestCompile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5+'
```